# How to change status bar icon color, if status bar color is white

Tags: java, android

I have changes my application's status bar color to white, after this status bar icon are not visible.

Comment: I think changing the theme of your app to Dark might help

Comment: try something like this <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> in your styles.xml

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code. Hope it works for you

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Add your activity style to this

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

if you need to this programmatically @Maitri's solution is the true one

Comment: How can this be done is devices less than version lolli pop ?